# how to run two files which are included in the eval method as a thread?

Tags: java, javascript, multithreading

In my project the code in the main method is like

```
jsEngine.eval(new FileReader(scrFile1));
jsEngine.eval(new FileReader(scrFile2));
```

I need to pass these files as threads. Is there any solutions for this problem??

Comment: What do you mean, "pass these files as threads"? Do you mean execute each script as a thread?

Comment: yes. I need to execute each script as thread.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rhino? Read [What is the lifecycle and concurrency semantics of Rhino Script Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936223/what-is-the-lifecycle-andconcurrency-semantics-of-rhino-script-engine) first. Then, if you are OK with the two concurrent evals' effects visible in each other, do something along the lines of:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    jsEngine.eval(new FileReader(scrFile1));
  }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    jsEngine.eval(new FileReader(scrFile2));
  }
});

t1.start();
t2.start();
```